# Can not get debugger in react native ios simulator to work

Tags: react-native, debugging, visual-studio-code, ios-simulator, metro-bundler

I am unable to get any sort of debugging working with react native ios simulator. I had this working before but after restarting a new project (RN went up from 0.69 to 0.70 in between this project change), it does not work anymore. I am trying to open the Debugger here:
[image: ios simulator]

I noticed that it used to have a Remote JS debugger option but that is now gone. When I click on Open Debugger, I get this in the metro terminal and nothing happens:
[image: metro terminal]

I have tried debugging in safari as well and the sources do not show and also have tried launch.json configurations with React Native Tools in vscode but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted to go back to RN 0.69.0 as it works as expected with that version. I opened an issue on the react-native project here: [React-Native on github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34615)